# livewire child component value null

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire

Parent component input value after form submit not null but child component value null.

```
<div class="row g-4">
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="single-info-input">
       <label class="label_title">{{ __('Title') }} </label>
        <input class="form--control" type="text" wire:model.defer="title">
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
          
<!-- child component -->
<div class="row g-4">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="single-info-input">
           <livewire:include-service>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

```
   public function serviceStore()
    {      
        dd($this->include_service_title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Livewire will not share properties like Blade component does.

Read more here: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#parameters